# I get better at guitar, I get better at playing the guitar or I get better at playing guitar

Tags: articles, grammaticality, nouns

Which of these sentences is correct in British english?

I get better at guitar

I get better at playing the guitar

I get better at playing guitar

And if all of them are correct, Which one is the most used in British english?

Comment: In British English (note the capital letter) we say _playing the guitar_ - or you could leave out the verb and say "I'm getting better at the guitar".